# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine, uppy

I'm getting an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null`. What does this mean? The source of the error is the line that says `id: file.meta['key'].match(/^cache\/(.+)/)[1]`:

```
uppy.on('upload-success', (file, response) => {
 // construct uploaded file data in the format that Shrine expects
 const uploadedFileData = {
  id: file.meta['key'].match(/^cache\/(.+)/)[1], // object key without prefix
  storage: 'cache',
  metadata: {
   size: file.size,
   filename: file.name,
   mime_type: file.type,
  }
 }

 // set hidden field value to the uploaded file data so that it's submitted
 // with the form as the attachment
 hiddenInput.value = JSON.stringify(uploadedFileData)
})
```

I think this is trying to select something at an index that doesn't exist, but then...what index does exist?

Comment: It’s in the match call after the Id key. There’s no matches so the square brackets return no property with an index of 1. Maybe try 0 instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that this `id: file.meta['key'].match(/^cache\/(.+)/)[1]` did not match the prefix in `Shrine.storage`. My prefix was `uploads/cache`. I just had to change it back to `cache`.